# Smack getPrivacyList method throws classCastException

Tags: android, smack

I am using Smack in an Android app for XMPP based communication. I am trying to create a privacy list using PrivacyManager. I have created a PrivacyList successfully, but when I try to access that list it returns ClassCastException. Here is the code:

```
PrivacyListManager privacyManager;
privacyManager = PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
PrivacyList privacyList = privacyManager.getPrivacyList("msg_block_list");
```

Investigating a bit more, I have found that the exception occurs in getRequest method in PrivacyListManager.java class on following line:

```
Privacy privacyAnswer =
            (Privacy) response.nextResult(SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
```

Here is the getRequest method:

```
private Privacy getRequest(Privacy requestPrivacy) throws XMPPException {
        // The request is a get iq type
        requestPrivacy.setType(Privacy.Type.GET);
        requestPrivacy.setFrom(this.getUser());

        // Filter packets looking for an answer from the server.
        PacketFilter responseFilter = new PacketIDFilter(requestPrivacy.getPacketID());
        PacketCollector response = connection.createPacketCollector(responseFilter);

        // Send create & join packet.
        connection.sendPacket(requestPrivacy);

        // Wait up to a certain number of seconds for a reply.
        Privacy privacyAnswer =
            (Privacy) response.nextResult(SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());

        // Stop queuing results
        response.cancel();

        // Interprete the result and answer the privacy only if it is valid
        if (privacyAnswer == null) {
            throw new XMPPException("No response from server.");
        }
        else if (privacyAnswer.getError() != null) {
            throw new XMPPException(privacyAnswer.getError());
        }
        return privacyAnswer;
    }
```

I have followed [this](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/privacy.html) tutorial for implementing PrivacyList. Anyone can help?

Comment: In what library all of this classes (`PrivacyListManager, PrivacyList, Privacy, SmackConfiguration`) are contained. There aren't such classes in android sdk. Did you define it yourself?

Comment: I have imported Smack API for that. Everything else works fine only PrivacyList causing problem.

Comment: By what class reponse object is defined?

Comment: By the way I didn't find any method such getRequest() in [this](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PrivacyListManager.html) documentation

Comment: I have updated the question and added getRequest method.

Comment: It's a private function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The XML file smack.providers was missing. I created the file with following contents and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- Providers file for default Smack extensions -->
<smackProviders> 
 <!-- Privacy -->
    <iqProvider>
        <elementName>query</elementName>
        <namespace>jabber:iq:privacy</namespace>
        <className>org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PrivacyProvider</className>
    </iqProvider>    
</smackProviders>
```

Comment: Where did you put the smack.providers xml file?

Answer (score 0):

`PacketCollector`'s method `getResult()` returns `Packet` object, but it could be any inherited from `Packet` class object, either `Message` or `Presence` or `IQ` (in `IQ` case you can use `(privacy)` cast, because `Privacy` is `IQ`'s child class). In your case it seems like you get object which is present in another hierarchy, than `Privacy` class.

Comment: Yes you are right it returns an object of PacketParserUtils class, but it's API responsibility to return correct class. How to fix it?

Comment: If you have a possibility, try to look at PacketCollector.java source code and customize it for yourself. I just can suppose that PacketParserUtils needs XMLPullParser to generate Packet, so there are next decisions: 1) You may edit PacketParserUtils.java for your needs. 2) You may include to your project org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser package and bind it with PacketParcelUtils.

Comment: What i have found that the PacketParserUtil nerver parses the jabber:iq:privacy stanzas.